# Função do Javascript erro. $.toJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou rodando um script que foi me passado por terceiros.
E esta dando o seguinte erro:

> TypeError: $.toJSON is not a function
>   `QtdeQuartos: $.toJSON(qtdQuartos),`

Comment: Você importou o arquivo de terceiros e o jquery?

Answer (score 5):

O script provavelmente faz uso da biblioteca [**jquery-json**](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/). Baixe-a e a inclua no seu projeto.

Answer (score 1):

[`toJSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> é um método do próprio JavaScript é chamado à partir do teu objeto.

```
var d = new Date();
var today = d.toJSON();
//Resultado: 2014-02-21T21:57:42.080Z
```

Recebendo isso via jQuery, você deve utilizar o método [`parseJSON`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John" }' );
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```